# Include referenced assembly without having to keep application in same directory as the referenced assembly

Tags: c#, winforms, reference

I am using `HTMLAgilityPack` with my C# `winform` application. I loaded HTMLAgilityPack from my hard drive using `Visual Studio`, as a Referenced Assembly. I then build my application and copy the output executable file to a new directory. If HTMLAgilityPack is not in the same directory as my output executable, an error occurs when attempting to run my executable saying  that the 'reference could not be found.' Is there some way to have the reference embedded into the executable file so that users will not need to carry around HTMLAgilityPack with them whenever they wish to move the file?

I look forward to your responses,

Evan

Comment: So the goal is to have a stand alone EXE?  Or are you having issues with a deployed application missing one or more DLLs?

Comment: A decent application is rarely 'just a file'. It is quite common to have a bunch of .DLLs, a .config and other supporting files. Just get used to moving a folder around.

Comment: @Henk Thank you, I think I might just have to accept this idea and move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that - but it isn't exactly trivial. You would subscribe to the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event, and when raised, *check* that it is looking for html agility pack (via the event args), then fetch the assembly BLOB from the embedded resource, use `Assembly.Load(theBlob)`, and *return* the `Assembly` instance.

Another, simpler, approach might be [`ilmerge.exe`](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630)

Finally, the GAC would avoid the need to have the file locally... but requires having it formally installed centrally instead. To be honest I would avoid the GAC here.

Comment: So Marc, I understand everything that you just posted does indeed work. I have to ask then - is it just smarter to force my users to carry the extra baggage? I don't want to spend the rest of my life using ilmerge...

Comment: @Evan I'd just deploy 2 files, personally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ILMerge utility to compine several assemblies into single file

ILMerge.exe /t:winexe /out:test.exe test1.exe test2.dll